# Update Realm from 0.82.1 to 0.89.1 .then I am getting null when fetch transaction id

Tags: android, realm

My model class

```
public class Transactions extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long transactionID;

    @Required
    private String transactionType;

    @Required
    private String amount;
}
```

getting null in trnsactionID.

```
long transactionID = realm.where(Transactions.class).max("transactionID").longValue() + 1;
```

Comment: Have you checked the breaking changes for all versions in between and adjusted your code accordingly?

Comment: yes i have checked

Comment: Is there data in your database?

Comment: You will get `null` if the database is empty.

Comment: But it was working in realm 0.82.1

Comment: `0.82.1` doesn't have `RealmQuery.max()` method. I believe you were using `RealmQuery.maxLong()` before which returns `long`. `RealmQuery.max()` returns `Number` which could be `null`. Please refer to the javadoc.

Comment: yes I was using .maxInt("transactionId")+1. but there was no null ,It was working